# How can I query this in a database?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

Table 1

```
Positon | Name | Nickname | Address
------------------------------------
   1    |   2  |    3     |    4
   5    |   6  |          |    7
   5    |   6  |          |    8
```

Table 2

```
Detail_seq | Details
--------------------
     1     |  manager
     2     |  Jimmy
     3     |  Jim
     4     |  Chicago
     5     |  Supervisor
     6     |  Mike
     7     |  Vancouver
     8     |  New York
```

and the output should be like this or something

```
Position: Manager
Name: Jimmy
Nickname: Jim
Address: Chicago

Position: Supervisor
Name: Mike
Nickname:
Address: Vancouver and New York
```

feel free to ask questions if it is not clear.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why put your details in a seperate table, just put them in your first table?

Comment: your output is really not clear

Comment: @TimSchmelter you says right but at least we can understand the question that is not clear

Comment: Please take a few seconds to look through the [ask] guide page. It'll help get the most from SO, and help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT Position=manager.details, 
       Name=Name.details, 
       Nickname=Nickname.details, 
       Address=Address.details 
FROM   table1 t1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 manager 
                    ON t1.positon = manager.detail_seq 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 name 
                    ON t1.name = name.detail_seq 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 Nickname 
                    ON t1.nickname = Nickname.detail_seq 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 Address 
                    ON t1.address = Address.detail_seq
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12ab2/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit extreme to store data this way. I can offer you to store the data categories in different tables. but if you insist, this should work

```
SELECT d1.details, d2.details, d3.details, d4.details
FROM main m, details d1, details d2, details d3, details d4
WHERE m.position = d1.detail_seq 
AND   m.name     = d2.detail_seq
AND   m.nickname = d3.detail_seq
AND   m.adress   = d4.detail_seq
```

Comment: No it shouldn't, the Nickname is empty on two rows so you need a `LEFT JOIN` not an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the details table one time for every detail:

```
  SELECT pos.Details, name.details, nick.details, adress.details
    FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 pos     ON pos.detail_seq = t1.position
    LEFT JOIN table2 name    ON name.detail_seq = t1.name
    LEFT JOIN table2 nick    ON nick.detail_seq = t1.nickname
    LEFT JOIN table2 address ON address.detail_seq = t1.address
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select (select details from t2 where t2.detail_seq=t1.position) position,
       (select details from t2 where t2.detail_seq=t1.name) Name,
       (select details from t2 where t2.det_seq=t1.nickname) nickname,
       (select details from t2 where t2.det_seq=t1.address) address
from t1 ;
```